# How to add partition table to existing EXT4 filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems, partition, mdadm, ext4

I have software RAID6 on 8x3TB disks (18TB), there is filesystem od device /dev/md1, but EXT4 can`t be bigger than 16TB so there is 2TB of free space. I would like to use this space. My first idea was to move filesystem a little bit from the beggining of disk and than make a partition table and proper partition describing my data. But maybe there is some smart hack to retrive those 2TB, and make it easy to add another disks to this array.

Copying this data, making partitions and restoring data is not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

ext4 can be bigger, just that you need a newer version of e2fstools, like [this one](http://downloads.whamcloud.com/public/e2fsprogs/latest/el6/RPMS/x86_64/).

Comment: Are you sure about that? e2fsprogs-1.42.9 can`t make partition bigger than 16TB.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the link to the proper version :). Actually the other one might still have worked. But this one from whamcloud I know it works because I used it myself.